# Use of wrapper for API in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

API calling
Assume that there are 3 APIs. Each API does exactly the same task(to give you weather details) but has different endpoints as follows:

API 1: Can only be used for India. Has methods named requestWeather(), requestWeatherDataForWeek()

API 2: Can only be used for the USA. Has methods named sendRequest(), weatherDataForWeek()

API 3: Can only be used for the UK. Has methods named getWeather(), getWeatherDataForWeek()

Select the country using the drop-down.
a. Select the API according to the country. API selection is programmatic, which will be decided according to the country selected by a user.

b. Write your code such that, any API can be used without disturbing the business logic.

c. There must be a limit on the number of requests that can be sent. Throw an error if no. of requests exceed the limit.

d.It does not require HTTP calls or APIs. Just create a wrapper for API with the specified method and return some dummy values.

```
weatherApp.config(function ($stateProvider,$urlRouterProvider) {

  $stateProvider

  .state('/', {
    templateUrl: 'home.html',
    controller: 'homeController'
  })

  .state('forecast', {
    url:"/forecast",
    templateUrl: 'forecast.html',
    controller: 'forecastController'
  })
  $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/");
});
weatherApp.service('cityService', function() {

  this.city = "New York, NY";

});
weatherApp.controller('Controller',['$scope','$state',function($scope,$state){
  $scope.clicked=function(){
    $state.go('forecast');
  };
}]);

weatherApp.controller('homeController', ['$scope', 'cityService', function($scope, cityService) {

  $scope.city = cityService.city;

  $scope.$watch('city', function() {
   cityService.city = $scope.city; 
 });

}]);
weatherApp.controller('forecastController', ['$scope', '$resource', '$routeParams', 'cityService', function($scope, $resource, $routeParams, cityService) {
  $scope.city = cityService.city;

  $scope.days = $routeParams.days || 2;
  $scope.weatherAPI = $resource("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/forecast/daily", { callback: "JSON_CALLBACK" }, { get: { method: "JSONP" }});

  $scope.weatherResult = $scope.weatherAPI.get({ q: $scope.city, cnt: $scope.days });

  $scope.convertToFahrenheit = function(degK) {

    return Math.round((1.8 * (degK - 273)) + 32);

  }
  $scope.convertToDate = function(dt) { 

    return new Date(dt * 1000);
  };
}]);
```

Tried this but how can we use wrapper for API?